# Passing a Boolean into Javascript from Flask

Tags: javascript, flask

I'm trying to use Python's Flask and Javascript to build a web map. So far I've managed to get Flask to perform an SQL query a ZIP, return some coordinates, and for the map to load that location.

Now I'm trying to control the 'visible:' part of the Javascript.

```
(function (w) {
var map = new ol.Map({
layers: [
         new ol.layer.Tile({
         title: 'Water color',
         visible: true,
         }),
         new ol.layer.Tile({
         title: 'OSM',
         visible: false,
         }),
        ],

        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform(w.latLon),
        })
    });
}(window));
```

Can that be done? The coordinates are passes in via w.latLon. Replacing `visible: true,` with `visible: w.OSM` and setting `OSM` to the string `true` doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Would using `1` and `0` as Boolean substitutes work instead?

Comment: Nice idea, but doesn't work for me. Set as 0, 1, '0' or '1' it always behaves as true. Interesting (to a complete novice like me) how 1 and 0, when I hardcode them in, behave as true and false.

Comment: Maybe adding in an intermediate function to parse the Flask output to JavaScript and vice versa would work.

Answer (score 2):

I had 2 problems.
1) I was failing to declare the variable in my template

2) I had to use this tojson device to stop it just passing a string, which is true

So, in my html template

```
OSM = {{ OSM|tojson }}
```

and in the javascript

```
visible : w.OSM,
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but if anyone's still wondering:

```
visible: JSON.parse('{{ w.OSM|tojson }}');
```